# What should be done with questions asking for game recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, game-recommendations, poll

**What should be done with a game-rec question posted to the site?** Please only give short and simple answers that the community can then enforce as a policy. This is not the place for discussion - other meta-threads have already done that.

The answer with the most *upvotes* in this discussion will be used as the chosen policy - see [this preparation question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/final-game-rec-showdown-preparation) for justification and explanation. The chosen policy will be a long-term one and will remain in effect until the moderators decide otherwise, as also decided in that other thread.

This question will be closed and the votes tallied on December 23rd, 2010.

---

For example of what game-recommendations questions look like, see questions tagged [game-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec) on the main site.

**Before voting, I strongly recommend reading the various discussions on this topic here on meta**, all tagged [game-recommendations](/questions/tagged/game-recommendations).

---

Today is December 23rd, 2010. Vote tally:

- **Close all game-recs unconditionally as shopping recommendation: 74**
- Allow game-recs that are specific enough (withdrawn): 70
- Only allow game-recs with accessibility constraints: 42
- Unconditionally allow them: 41
- Close and point to area-51 proposal: 14
- Leave the choice to the moderators: 10
- Close as off-topic, redirect to a few select CW topics: 7
- Invert the closing life-cycle (withdrawn): 3

Unfortunately, the numbers show the amount of division among our users regarding this decision - but in my eyes any decision is better than no decision, and I will go on to enforce the chosen policy until the elected moderators decide differently.

To anyone who still supports game-rec questions: I urge you to [commit to the game-rec area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations?referrer=CfnaKMoG-dz7_uTkKsMvLw2) (notice this is a referral link; if you don't like me just go to [the proposal directly](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations)).

Comment: REMINDER TO EVERYONE: As per [Oak's preparatory question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/final-game-rec-showdown-preparation), downvotes will not contribute to a given solution's score.

Comment: Downvotes do affect the order in which proposals are ordered, however.

Comment: Y'know, we never did discuss what should be done in the event of a tie...

Comment: Like badp said, downvotes will have the tendency to affect what answers people give more attention to. It's a small thing though, and I don't think there's a solution for it anyway.

Comment: @Bruce: Simple: [ __view this question by newer posts first__ ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1491?tab=newest#tab-top).

Comment: @Grace the amount of votes is large enough that I doubt a tie will occur, but if it does we can extend the deadline by a few days and then check again, and repeat until it is resolved.

Comment: Wargh, why is it that whenever you're around to ignite things in chat, I'm at work? Ah well, if you could, give Ivo a jab in the ribs for me [with this link](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/712/can-we-use-meta-for-gaming-related-discussions/713#713 "I could make yet another joke on your name, if I wanted. I've got 13 more.") ♪

Comment: @Grace if the future mods will perceive the chosen policy as too harmful after it has been in effect for a while, they could start a new poll - as the 2nd sentence in the 2nd paragraph says.

Comment: I would rather we don't implement something harmful in the first place for them to have to deal with. But I suppose it's far too late for that discussion.

Comment: I have to be honest, this vote was not conducted with enough preparation and for-planning and the result has been [disastrous](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations/1493#1493). I'm going to have to ask, at this time, that we abandon this vote and reconvene when we have a better understanding of what it is that we want to accomplish, and a better method for doing so.

Comment: @tzenes I think the question is wrong, we may just restart the poll by replacing "What should be done questions asking for game recommendations?" by "Should we accept questions asking for game recommendations?". The possible answer should then be Yes or No. I think we should either accept or reject all of them. Otherwise it just lead to this : http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations/1519#1519

Comment: @Dav Honestly I see no problem with some attempts to lighten the mood up.

Comment: @tze I think it's too late for closing. We had a preparatory question to come up with criticism, now the ball is rolling. We can use the feedback for next matters, but honestly I feel the single worst thing we can do is wait until we come up with the mythical Perfect Policy Process to get a Pretty Perfect Policy out of it.

Comment: @badp I cannot think of anything being worse than disenfranchising our users.

Comment: @tzenes Let's remove the close button then.

Comment: @badp that'd disenfranchise the users who voted to close

Comment: I'm starting to side more with not restarting the vote. I stand by my decision in convincing the policy to be removed because as a community member and as a moderator, it would be irresponsible of me to let a hole-filled policy be implemented simply because of my own failure to fully explain the problem beforehand and the consequent failure of the system to provide any means to validate the enforceability of a broken policy. Letting the voting proceed as if there wasn't anything critically wrong with the policy follows the same ignorance as the meaningless law which the policy proposes.

Comment: Does this fully justify negating all those votes? I probably won't ever be forgiven for this. But as someone I respect once said, sometimes a person in a position of power has to protect the community from the "mob". In this case, it's not a mob, but the innocent majority who are simply unaware of the flaws. This poll would have been far more of a clown charade than it is now if we let a policy get implemented even after it is identifiably recognized as a faulty, broken mess.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure I like closing this question.  I realize @tzenes has issues with the one answer getting pulled out, but I think it is important to note that a) he did not vote for that answer, and b) no one who did vote for that answer has complained of being disenfranchised.  Personally, I voted for it and I have no problem with it being withdrawn by the original poster.

Comment: @Grace if what you say is true why even bother with a vote?  If your job as Mod is ultimately to protect us from a bad answer, then why not move directly to a verdict handed down by you?  The issue here is not that removing a hole filled policy is wrong, as much as, removing all those people's votes is wrong.  If this vote is a charade why even bother to let it proceed?  Everything you just said can be executed just as easily (in fact, even more so) without the poll as with it.

Comment: @tzenes I'm not trying to sabotage this vote and create unrest within the trust of people in the system. And I honestly don't believe I have done so. What we're doing here is a *basic informal poll* done by a fairly lax community. Maybe some users are hurt, while others will read the reason and realize "Oh, hey, that was a good idea to remove it", and yet others will just shrug and move on. It's even written in the second paragraph, that if the policy is determined as such it may be overturned regardless of its initial support. Letting it run through first wouldn't even be pointless formality.

Comment: @Grace if its a pointless formality then why do you need it?  Issue a directed verdict and we can be done with this.  Why do you need the poll? If we're going to poll then we can't change the rules half way through because we don't like the results, that's not fair.  If we don't need the poll then let's skip it and move on to what we know is best.

Comment: @tzenes No rules were changed, and once again I'd appreciate it if you stopped those hurtful accusations about my motivation. We're running an informal poll with only three ground rules: how long the poll runs, what metric to determine the winner, and policy lifetime post-implementation. The rest is already understood to be quite an ad-hoc process, like handling ties or challenging a decision. It was designed open to be flexible since we didn't know what to expect, and I believe the community is capable of understanding and adapting to unexpected events or revelations of knowledge like this.

Comment: Look @Grace I'm not trying to hurt you or accuse you of something here.  We all entered into this poll with the same assumption: What I upvote will win (as you called it the metric).  Unfortunately, that isn't true for everyone.  Some people's upvotes are being removed.  Now I don't know how understanding and adapting the community is, but I do have a sense of right and wrong, and it seems wrong to say `The answer with the most upvotes in this discussion will be used as the chosen policy`, and then remove answers you don't like (for whatever reason). It _feels_ dishonest

Comment: I want game-rec gone as much as anybody (maybe more than some), but I can't justify this cost to myself.  If we are capable of determining what the right thing is without a poll, let's just do that.  If we need a poll, then let's structure one where people aren't being lead to believe one thing, while another is happening. I don't really care which one we go with, but I can't sit by and watch something like this poll happen.  Now if you want to over rule me, you can, you have that power; but I'm here saying: `This is wrong`.

Comment: @tzenes You're not being very successful at that when you're continually downplaying all of the reasons for these events occurring as nothing but pettiness and malice towards one section of the community, especially considering that pettiness and malice aren't a part of *any* of the aforementioned reasons. It feels dishonest because that "wrong" you claim is an oversimplification of the situation that adamantly refuses to attribute any relevance of outside factors to the events that transpired.

Comment: I've asked you to understand that what has happened here did *not* occur because of any like or dislike of game rec, and in fact not to do with game-rec at all. In fact, I will openly admit that not only have I refused to vote on badp's answer (my vote is locked as null as of the first day), but that I had in fact voted for the allow-all option. Of course, my opinion is largely irrelevant because it wasn't a part of the decision making process. And until you choose to actually acknowledge the relevance of why the option *actually* was removed, there isn't really any hope for a resolution here.

Comment: @Grace I'm not trying to downplay the reasons, or even suggest they were petty and malicious; if you got that impression I apologize.  I think the reasons were good and noble, but they don't justify doing this.  The reasons are sort of irrelevant to whether or not people were mislead.  Misleading people _feels_ wrong, and I'm not willing to do it even for these reasons (good as they may be).  I've offered two valid options: Restart the poll with [fixed answers](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/298), or, if that isn't expedient enough, issue a directed verdict.

Comment: @tzenes I'm not seeing where people are actually being misled. There's no underhanded trickery, no hidden ploy, no attempt to cast attention elsewhere. We made a mistake, we employed measures to correct it, and we announced that the mistake happened so that people are aware of it. We're being very honest here about what happened, and we have not changed anything about our promise to make a decision, unless we actually delay said decision. And thus far, many users are satisfied with this. Users from both factions, in fact.

Comment: @Grace everyone who cast his vote, prior to the announcement, was mislead to believe it would be treated the same as any other vote.  This is not the case.  If we had nipped this answer when it was 2-3 votes, then at least people would have been informed.  Instead, this went to become the most popular option (and likely winner) before being removed.  Certainly this was not planned with malice or deception, but people were deceived.  If the issue is that mistakes happen, let's just restart the poll so that people know what they're getting into.

Comment: @tzenes People knew what they were getting into by voting in an informal poll where not only are the options subject to change, but they can be edited. Half the policies here are not what they were originally proposed as; what about the users who wanted those first revisions? They may return and revert their choice if they find it appropriate, because we made no secret of the dynamic nature of this poll. It is no different than their original vote being removed. Furthermore, if the issue is with disenfranchisement, it shouldn't matter whether it has 3 votes or 66 votes.

Comment: We picked an informal system and people understood that it was going to be informal and that the options may change over the course of the 3 weeks. This isn't a flaw that makes this system unusable for our purposes, because we don't *need* some super-complicated, rigidly structured election system to make this policy. A flexible, dynamic poll is a functional system and we have never advertised it as anything more static. We *are* treating their votes the same as everyone else's. They don't get to be more valuable just because there were a lot of them in one week.

Comment: @Grace I'm not sure why you're calling a poll to decide the formal policy for the site as informal, I kind of think of that as a specious argument.  I've already pointed out that the voting system doesn't need to be `super-complicated` to achieve its goal. Finally, I don't see how you can say their votes are treated the same as everyone else's.  If that option now gets the highest number of votes it won't be treated the same.  You've made a large number of assertions but provided no evidence for them.

Comment: I should clarify, its not that there isn't evidence for why they are true, but why they are related.  They all seem like good reasons that a policy shouldn't be decided by a poll, not good reasons that this poll should be reopened.

Comment: @tzenes It's an informal poll because we didn't pre-define the options before hand, which is the general process for a formal poll. The fact the policy is to be formal doesn't mean the process to pick it has to be. As far as vote treatment, all I did was "remove policies with critical issues in its structural integrity". If you can point me to an equivalently huge hole in any of the other policies, I have every reason to suggest its removal. Likewise, for any option that is withdrawn, its votes don't count, and this is being applied on two posts right now. There is no special treatment.

Comment: What I'm giving are reasons why the poll is fine as being informal with dynamic options, why the actions don't alter the integrity of our poll, and consequently why the poll isn't so marred by the recent events that we need to drop everything and rehost it.

Comment: Sure, at first it looked messy after I suggested the withdrawal, and I considered the validity of a reset. But in retrospect, and thanks to Oak and Jason Berkan and the others, I was shown that really, this isn't a huge mess compared to before. It's the same mess we've had since day 1, same mess that people want to support, same mess dedicated to ending this stupid war, and same mess which people from all factions still think works even after the withdrawal. The fact it's a mess is maybe unsightly, but it still gets the job done, and I hope it will get that job done by December 23rd.

Comment: As I tend to agree with Grace, I'm voting to re-open this question. I do not consider this abuse of mod-power since there's a 3/5 re-open vote at the moment and Grace would have also voted the same - so that's two of us, and we both have >3k rep. All that said, @tzenes, I do understand your disapproval - it's just that I, like Grace, do not see it with the same amount of... gravity, I suppose. In any case I think that it's better to let this poll finish and then have the new mods change the chosen policy if they want, than to outright cancel this.

Comment: So my concern with this explanation is that the definition for @Grace's "policies with critical issues in its structural integrity" is completely subjective.  I hold the opinion that ANY game-rec has the same issue.  This is the essence of why we are voting on the issue of game-rec to begin with. If everyone shared my opinion there'd be no need for the vote.  However, not everyone does, and some percentage of those 66 people actually think that the status quo is acceptable.  I don't agree with them and it sounds like neither of you do, but that doesn't give me the right to null their opinion.

Comment: At this point we are just removing opinions with which we disagree, and if we're going to do that, then there really isn't a reason to have a vote.  Then again I've said all this before.  If you guys want to over rule (through votes or mod privileges) me on this issue there isn't a lot else I can do. I still think this is the second worst possible outcome.

Comment: @Oak - would it be possible for a mod to touch all the answers in this question?  I have some upvotes I would like to remove, for various and sundry reasons.

Comment: @Jason done, at least for all serious answers.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The solution is simple: consider game-recs are shopping recommendations. We don't do the latter, so we don't do the former.

I propose a new close reason for emphasis, so that askers don't start arguing on the close reason blurb:

> ## Shopping list
>
> This question asks for buying or playing recommendations. List questions are [not suitable](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/997/handling-game-recommendations-how-can-we-solve-these-two-problems-of-quality) for this site and are better handled on [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/bridge).

The first link should really only link to a page with Grace's essay.

Comment: I dig it!!!!!!! (15 chars...)

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that using the chat room has a higher rep requirement than asking questions.

Comment: @Bruce - true but it's not a particularly high requirement ;)

Comment: Gotta agree with Bruce, if we're going to ask people to use the chatroom for game recs, can that rep requirement be lowered? Not sure of the technical possibilities available with the SE platform but I'm assuming a single special chat room is out of the question.

Comment: Could there be a chatroom called "Game Recommendations" which would be accessible to anyone? I don't know if it would work or if it would just turn into chaos, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @Bruce We figured that the one issue with that is that there are more people in the main chat room, and a lot more activity in general. A separate Rec Room is possible to get frozen for inactivity. Plus, the majority of people (if not all) opposed to game rec are only opposed to its presence on the parent Q&A, and have been happy to help in the main chat room.

Comment: The rep requirement shouldn't be changed for the chat room.  A new user can easily gain rep as is without cluttering up the site.  We're not metacritic.  If you're going to demand a game rec from the community, you should start by becoming a contributing member of the community.

Comment: I don't think it's bad to have a minimal rep requirement to get help on Chat. It shows you are willing to help others in exchange for getting help yourself.

Comment: also +1 for dealing with it in the most generic sense possible!

Comment: No grey areas is exactly what is needed. +1

Comment: Game rec questions are good. But they do not belong on this site. Period.

Comment: If you post a question in the chatroom, aren't you only going to get answers from people who happen to be in the chatroom at that moment?

Comment: @Kyralessa I'm afraid so. After all you can't get answers from people who don't visit the site either, now, can you?

Comment: @badp, seriously?  You don't see the difference?

Comment: @Kyralessa - so what, fewer people will read your question and even less will get to answer (need 20 rep). Beats having more people read your question with nobody at all being able to answer ;) (In before a retort about comments: you need __50__ rep to comment.)

Comment: @badp, You need 20 rep to answer?  Maybe that's true, but that's kind of odd if so.

Comment: @Kyralessa No, you just can't answer _closed_ questions. That's because these questions should be closed.

Comment: @Kyra Keep in mind that chat transcripts are maintained forever, so even if nobody is in the chat room at the time, if someone comes in later they can read your question, and they can answer with an @ comment and it will show up in your mailbox when you return.

Comment: [As I've written before](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/943/game-recommendation-room-experiment/990#990), I consider chat *extremely* unsuitable for recommendations. Even if we decide to prohibit all game-rec questions, I think redirecting to chat is a terrible idea.

Comment: @Oak, what other place would you suggest then?

Comment: I guess [the area51 game-rec suggestion](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations)... or nothing.

Comment: @Oak that's unnecessarily unfriendly :)

Comment: @badp it's better than redirecting to somewhere as inadequate as chat - at least that's my opinion. Also, redirecting to area51 is not totally useless, users might end up committing.

Comment: @oak I'm not really bought by your chat argument to be honest... sure, chat isn't the bestest thing out there for the purpose, but if I could downvote that proposal I would. We failed to host game recs because of engine issues -- another site won't fix that.

Comment: I wonder, how would a game-rec reddit work instead?

Comment: My opinion on the whole "engine vs. game-rec" is that it only breaks because we have an established meaning for votes that is scaled to the full site, a meaning which doesn't match the needs of recs that are rated on scales of the individual questions. The issues are not with the engine, but with the engine in conjunction with our standard Q&A. We can't house them together, but if game-rec has its own home then we largely cancel the big Values Dissonance issue as well as the scale problem. At least, that's my take on it.

Comment: @Grace That doesn't fix the values dissonance with what reputation is meant to be I'm afraid... but at the end of the day, that's a problem for another meta.

Comment: I agree with @Oak that pointing the person to area51 might be best. It's not very friendly, but it's better than the chat and, if worded carefully, a good deal of people will end up checking it out. The one disadvantage I can think of: *That might cause a lot of cases of commit-and-forget.*

Comment: Also, we could add an extra (very short) sentence to the end of @badp's close reason linking to area51. Just let the user decide what he prefers.

Comment: @Bruce We can probably come up with a lot of different resources in-house and out-of-house. I think those would be better stuffed in our FAQ (much like how Stack Overflow links Super User and Server Fault) than enumerated on the close reason. Besides, should this policy win we'll need a better Meta post than what badp is currently linking.

Answer (score 54):

> ### This policy has been withdrawn from the running
>
> Due to the overwhelming quantity of flaws that outweigh the positives of the policy *Allow game-rec as **Community Wiki** if they are **specific enough to only have a few answers***, it is now withdrawn as an option. These flaws include but are not limited to:
>
> - Community Wiki cannot be enabled on questions by the author, requiring hefty moderator intervention
> - The asker is incapable of determining whether the question is appropriate due to an inherent lack of knowing the answers
> - The majority of game-rec would remain closed, and most specifically the majority of game-rec that would help the greater number of people
> - The arbitrary measure of potential answer quantity leads to conflict, resulting in no change from our current situation
> - Perhaps most importantly, quantity is not an effective measure of broadness - questions with equivalently broad scopes (i.e. just swap Platform A for Platform B) can attract completely different question quantities. This gaping hole in the policy is actually a very common incident that will likewise lead to many disputes on both the parent site and the Meta site
>
> As a result of the previous point, **the policy is impossible to enforce without either the letter of the law** (*low answer quantity rec are allowed*) **or the spirit of the law** (*narrowly scoped rec are allowed*) **being violated in a consistent fashion**. The policy cannot successfully accomplish what it is intended to do, and would result in continued conflict which the policy is incapable of defending.
>
> #### Allowing game recommendations is still viable
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience and the effect of this on the many supporters of this proposal. Please understand that this decision was done in the interest of the site and community to function, not as a method to support either side of the debate.
>
> The numerous flaws which cause this policy to be unviable have little to do with the nature of game recommendations. So if you still want them, **please consider redirecting your support to [the unconditional allowance of game recommendations as if they were like any other question we deal with](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations/1505#1505).**
>
> Alternatively, if you still feel that there needs to be some other form of limitation beyond the normal standards we have for other questions, feel free to develop a new criteria besides answer quantity and propose it as its own option.

---

I believe game-rec questions should be kept open (as community-wiki) as long as they are **very** specific. Questions not specific enough (examples follow) should be closed as too subjective and the chatroom should be recommended.

The reason is that if the question is specific enough, it ceases to be a huge list, it doesn't abuse the site's resources any more than regular questions, and it also becomes a lot less subjective.
**|Edit here|** As a general rule: **If the request is specific enough to have only a few answers, definitely less than 15, than it should be kept open. If, just by looking at the question, you can tell there are 30+ answers for it, close it.** This is not dependant on the community's ability to answer, but rather on the amount of options available. It *is* subjective on the moderator's ability to pre-emptively identify whether the number of answers will be large or not. To those who think that's too subjective, there's also ChrisF's answer.

For example, I think it's a shame that [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/which-brain-training-and-puzzle-games-for-the-nintendo-ds-dont-require-quick-rea) got closed. It's a lot more specific than just "DS and puzzle", and isn't *that* subjective.

On the other hand, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11877/good-games-for-7-year-old-girl-closed) is clearly too subjective, and would have suffered from all the flaws associated to big-lists.

*Unlocked - in case anyone wants to continue in comments. However, it will be locked if people attempt to rollback the original proposer's decision to withdraw this policy.*

Comment: I would shy away from sustaining a grey area. If you want to get a recommendation, come have a chat in the Chatroom. Else good luck elsewhere

Comment: I really think that the focused and specific questions do provide a value to this site and the users. Keeping them community-wiki would negate the problem of people voting for their favorite games rather than a correct answer if I understand the function of community-wiki correctly.

Comment: @Blake It stops reputation, but it doesn't stop votes.

Comment: Note that it is no longer possible for ordinary users to mark a *question* as community wiki.  Because of this, moderator intervention would be required in every case of game-rec.

Comment: Terrible solution.  You just made the criteria for closing the question totally independent of the question itself, and instead entirely dependent on the community's ability to answer it.

Comment: I believe the first example would probably be allowed under ChrisF's modification of badp's proposal.  It is specifically targeting games for someone with physical limitations.

Comment: @Christian - I would add that the bolded rule above also makes it very difficult to judge if you are asking a valid game-rec question.  If I'm asking, I'm very likely to not know how many games are available that meet my criteria.  That's why I'm asking.  Further, would we close a game-rec if it got too many answers?  Would the number of allowed answers vary with the "average number of answers for regular questions"?  (The average is currently 2.07 answers per question.)

Comment: @sjohnston Personally, I wonder why, when our helpful content is having the answers people are looking for, that we would promote the questions that are a lot harder to find answers for and discourage what we can more readily provide answers for.

Comment: @Christian: I clarified the criteria, it might have been misunderstood. I don't think it depends on the community's ability. Instead, it depends on how restrictive the question is.

Comment: @sjohnson: I think both your points are valid, and I can't really think of an answer to them.

Comment: What about questions like these where nobody in the community realized "there're [sic] thousands of" answers for it? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10395/2d-platform-arcade-games-with-complex-graphics-and-animation-side-scrollers

Comment: I have to agree with @IvoFlipse.  Either all questions or none.  Gray areas will only lead to future conflict of the exact same nature we've been having already.

Comment: @Christian:Strictly as it is written right now, I'd classify that question as valid. But I'd advise the author to ask for a game that satisfies ALL of his criteria simultaneously, and not just some of them.

Comment: How is a very specific game-rec distinguishable from a identify-this-game question?

Comment: @badp: Though they are distinguishable, I do agree that they are extremely similar. That is partially why I support that neither should be closed.

Comment: @badp: A what?.

Comment: @Bruce Connor They are indistinguishable.  Anybody could fool this entire site and bypass the game-rec controversy by simply disguising his game-rec questions as identify-this.  "I'm looking for a game where..."

Comment: @Christian: Yes, a person could fool the site like that. Banishing game-rec questions might indirectly cause that behaviour, and might lead to authentic identify-this questions being closed from paranoia. Allowing very specific game-rec questions would generally avoid this, since there would be no reason for someone to fool the community like that.

Comment: _...site's resources any more than regular questions, and it also becomes a lot less subjective. __|Edit here|__ As a general rule: If..._

Comment: Oh, that was actually intentional =). I just wanted people to noticed I had edited something in the middle of the text.

Comment: @Bruce Why 15? Most people don't look past the first answer, much less the first 5, so why 15, that feels very arbitrary.  What's more how does that solve the other problems of game-rec, namely: `answers with little to no addition content than their relation to the original question; voting schemes are proportional to popularity, not accuracy; there is no end to the question as people continue to supply answers; and it promotes the value of opinions over facts.`  The problem with game-rec is not _just_ that there are tons of answers (and again, 15 feels like a lot).

Comment: @tzenes: 15 is a way to evaluate the question, I chose it arbitrarily and can be changed, the emphasis is on `definitely less than`. So, unless you're sure it has less possible answers than that, close it.

Comment: @tzenes: I figured the statistical error of a human trying to determine the number of possible answers (mean-square deviation) is of several answers, so it makes no sense to stipulate an upper limit of 5 (no mod could be that precise with their prediction). The number 15 is intended to account for the mod's imprecision, so `definitely less than` means `your guess + your uncertainty < 15`. It does NOT mean "you think it's less than 15". Again, 15 was chosen arbitrarily, it could be lowered to 10. I don't think it should be lowered to 5, because nobody can be that precise.

Comment: @tzenes: On the other stuff: When the question is restrictive enough, voting due to popularity isn't that much of a problem (the question was very accurate, so it's easier to rate answers based on accuracy). Again, a very accurate question does value facts over opinions. `I need a game that follows the following criteria` is asking for facts, as long as the criteria are restrictive enough there will be little space for opinions (sure, "little" is more than "zero", but a lot of regular questions leave a little space for opinions too).

Comment: @tzenes:The questions could be closed after an answer is accepted, to avoid continual supply of answers (which will be very sporadic if the question was very specific). And, finally, it doesn't solve the `answers with no addition ...` thing.

Comment: @tzenes: I didn't want to write all of this on my actual answer, partially because this thread is for voting. But I think it's ok to discuss this stuff in the comments. I agree this option has a few flaws, but I think it's acceptable. After all, if any solution was perfect there would be no point in voting. ;-)

Comment: @Bruce so you're talking about a lot of different things here and I'm going to focus on just one for the moment before we move to others: `When the question is restrictive enough, voting due to popularity isn't that much of a problem.`  This is kind of a bold statement as we've [seen in the past](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6083) it [isn't true](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4369/102).  Now I'm not asking you to contest those examples, but if you think that criteria will reduce the poor voting pattern, you're going to have to supply a reason why.

Comment: To date there has been no evidence to remotely suggest people will [change their habits](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/997/handling-game-recommendations-how-can-we-solve-these-two-problems-of-quality/1004#1004) on [game-rec] questions, and voting based on popularity has been a habit.  Now we can arbitrarily set down rules to try and enforce this, but as enforcement is largely a community based activity you have to get the community to most of the moderating, and as it is the community you're trying to moderate that's not a _De Facto_ solution.

Comment: I can see 15 being a method of evaluation. But what actually makes it a *good* method of evaluation? I know I'm repeating myself here, but why is it a good idea to shield ourselves from the questions which we stand the greatest potential to actually receive answers for? Restricting game-rec to only the questions which few answers exist, what purpose does this serve? To clutter up the site with the most esoteric of questions which may never get those answers?

Comment: @Grace: The idea behind the method is that it allows us to avoid the questions that present all the issues cited above by tzenes, while still allowing other questions that don't have that many issues. It is based on the assumption that game-rec questions that are restrictive enough actually avoid most of those issues (though, admittedly, they still carry a couple of the issues). If this assumption is correct, than the method is good (though certainly not perfect).

Comment: Quantity of potential answers doesn't really affect the voting scheme. If someone has a very esoteric restriction which happens to allow a game like Portal to get mentioned, it's [going to attract many votes](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/a-gamer-wakes-up-from-a-10-year-coma-what-games-should-he-play/9543#9543). That link isn't an actual esoteric restriction, but its point is to simply point out the discrepancy that occurs when a popular game happens to get suggested.

Comment: But let's put that aside and think about why we're even allowing game rec in the first place. What good does it do to open up game rec if people can only ask those few questions which happen to be most scarce? What if all I'm interested in is a very specific costume design, which happens to make a fair enough number of qualifying games? Does increasing our portfolio to "Recommendations for only the most exotic and specific of tastes" really help that much? Is that worth all the trouble that this difficult-to-enforce policy would entail?

Comment: @Grace: I've been giving a lot of thought to that specific point since yesterday. I do agree that games like Portal will skyrocket even with esoteric questions, that is primarily a consequence of the whole system we are working with here, and the only way to absolutely avoid that is ban game-rec for good. Considering that broad requests will certainly have popular games as an acceptable answer, restricting ourselves to only the esoteric ones will at least cut out a chunk of that problem.

Comment: @Grace: The good it does is that you are actually helping someone who is not just being lazy. Truth is, most game-rec questions will have a list (or dozens of lists) associated to them somewhere on the internet. All of the broad and vague requests could certainly have been answered by Google in a matter of minutes, and the person is either lazy or just asking for the sake of it. Esoteric questions, on the other hand, might not have a decent list out there. Even if one does have a couple, it is safe to assume the person just didn't find it (in which case we can just link the list as an answer).

Comment: @Grace:Either way, keeping an esoteric question allows us to help someone who might not have found an answer by himself, while filtering out most of the "just lazy" cases. When a question "happens to make a fair enough number of qualifying games", it probably (but not certainly) already has several lists somewhere. The criteria can (and maybe should) be improved, I just think it would be a shame to close questions that we can really help with and the answer is not easy to find (if at all).

Comment: @Bruce so when I said "I don't want you to contest these examples," it wasnt because I was being narcisistic, it was because it was irrelivent. You still haven't given a reason why specificity solves this problem. It might also interest you to know the asker of that question didn't think most ofthe answers were relavent despite what the votes seem to indicate

Comment: @tzenes: My bad =). Really. I actually read "I want you to contest these examples". I have deleted my previous comment and I'm now writing an actual answer.

Comment: @tzenes: It doesn't solve the problem. As I mentioned, the only way to solve that problem is to ban [game-rec]s for good, and I'd rather find some compromise. The idea is that every broad question will invariably have popular game titles as answers, so cutting them out helps a lot. A very specific question may or may not have this issue depending on what it asks, and I'd rather give it the chance.

Comment: @tzenes: A lot of times (as in your example) the asker already mentions these popular games in the question. Based on the above, I assume that the answers will be relatively unknown more often than not. This means that popularity voting will only generate a few votes and won't cause as much discrepancy as it does now. That's why I said it `isn't that much of a problem`. In the cases when a popular game does show up on an answer, it will skyrocket as usual.

Comment: Why is it only a shame to close questions which we can help with when the answer is not easy to find? If someone has difficulty finding the answer on their own, does it really matter whether it's because there are no resources versus because that person already played the 40 games listed elsewhere and wants to know what else there is? What makes helping one person with an exotic taste so valuable that we can allow it under restricted circumstances but not a question that can help potentially hundreds of people with not-so-exotic tastes?

Comment: @Bruce So What I got from your comment is that it doesn't solve the problem, but its not much of a problem, and I'm sort of missing that last leap of logic.  Why is it that voting by popularity isn't much of a problem?  Why is stratifying our votes based not on your stringent criteria, but instead on people's preference ok?  Why is: `only a few votes` any better than tons of votes if they're still being misappropriated.

Comment: @Grace "Easy to find" is totally subjective, and no gamer with "exotic taste" could possibly find any value whatsoever in any game recommendations from this site.  The only shame is in keeping these questions open for such terrible reasons.

Comment: Out of all the possibilities, this is the absolute worst one.  I would rather allow them unconditionally than deal with this ridiculous idea.  I'm in disbelief that this "solution" has such strong vote support.  I'm disgusted.

Comment: @Grace : I do think that we should allow the generic ones as well. They could indeed help hundreds of people. But so many points have been raised against [game-rec]s that I decided to offer an option that would allow us to at least help some people, without suffering from all of the drawbacks.

Comment: @tzenes: It's OK because it's the best you're gonna get. If I wanted a TPS futuristic game for the GameCube, I wouldn't mind people voting based on preference as long as all the answers satisfy the criteria I asked for. If the answers are few, and if the asker is genuinely interested, he'll end up looking up each one of them anyway. A couple extra votes to one answer shouldn't keep the others from being read, they won't be awarding rep anyway, and the answer to end up permanently on top will be whichever the asker chooses. In which ways do you believe a few misappropriated votes are harmful?

Comment: By the way, the actual criteria is something that could be defined by a second voting. The point is to not close the questions that are evaluated as specific enough.

Comment: This *is* the criteria defining phase. We're past the preliminaries... that's what the past 4 months have been. The whole reason we're doing this now is to get things settled and defined instead of the existing "policies", which I might remind you that we started off as a non-specific "It is acceptable if it is specific enough". The purpose is to bring an end to all of this, and prolonging that by needing a second vote is not productive.

Comment: I vote that this answer be discounted from the tallying at the end of all of this because it's such a disgracefully terrible option that essentially leaves us off EXACTLY where we have been already since the inception of this site.  This isn't a solution at all; it's just nonsense.

Comment: Ok, I apologize for that then. Being specific enough is indeed the point of this option. The examples serve to quantify how specific it should be. I thought the effort of generalizing the examples could be left to a next step, once established that specificity was the rule. Since that's not the case, I'll just leave the criteria as it is.

Comment: This policy is still to large to be applicable without confusion. If there is around 20 answer for a question, we are in a gray zone. Another problem is that there new game that come to the market, so a question that have 10 possible answer right now could get 30 in a year.

Comment: @bruce do I really have to explain why misappropriated votes are harmful? I kind of tought we were beyond that. Voting is the system our site is based on how we tell good answers from the random noise on the internet. If someone comes to a question without knowing about the answers themselves its how they judge relavency. Selecting an answer as accepted only indicates which helped the op not which are relavent.For a question like game-rec where more than one answer is applicable voting is how people choose which to play. If popular but wrong games are getting up voted people are being mislead.

Comment: How many $50 highly voted games  are you going to buy before you say: "These people have no clue what theyre talking about!"

Comment: I will bring up a nice example of quantity rules being extremely difficult to maintain: suppose I ask about Roguelikes for the Android. There are very few, so it is acceptable by your metrics. Yet, Roguelikes for Windows would get closed pretty fast as there are a number of them. In the actual nature of these questions, the only difference is the platform. The quantity of options on each platform is largely irrelevant - they are identical in how specific they are. Why does one get to live while the other one must be closed? How shall we handle the constant disputes which will result?

Comment: @tzenes That is the point. As long as the suggested games meet the requirements I asked for, there *is* no wrong answer. In objective terms, all correct answers are equally precise, and using votes to measure precision pointless anyway. As long as the few answers that do not satisfy the question's requirements (the noise) are downvoted as any wrong answer should be, I see no harm in letting the votes represents popularity. If they represented precision they would just be even anyway.

Comment: @tzenes And I said "look up each one" not "buy each one". A [game-rec] question would be a pointer towards games that meet what you are looking for. It would tell you of games that you might never have found out existed, allowing you to look for more info on them, not buy them immediately.

Comment: @Grace The number of options in each platform will have to be considered relevant. I was aware of that when I proposed it, but I hadn't thought of the disputes that might arise. One answer could be to have the following closing message `As decided by voting, [game-rec] questions not specific enough to have only a few answers are problematic and belong in the chat room.` That would link to this voting and to your essay on the issues. I personally would be ok with that, but I'm not impartial. If people continue to have problems with it, than it would be a very big issue.

Comment: (The wording on the above message can be better thought out.)

Comment: My writings with regards to handling game recommendations have always been on the entire subject, not on quantity of answers. This is because I believe that quantity is completely irrelevant to building quality answers, and that is what we strive to do as a Q&A website. Quantity is also not indicative of how "specific" a particular question is, and I have been arguing this since the issue first erupted. After all, the quantity of answers isn't a problem if they're all correct! They make the lists harder to maintain but that's a lot less than the moderation for this policy.

Comment: I have problems with this criteria because it is nonsensical. Do you really expect that the Windows user will simply accept that "We decided that even though your question is just as specific as the Android, it is too broad for our site because we say so"? We cannot defend such a closure in good faith, because this is following the letter of the law for no reason other than it being the letter of the law. This criteria has bare ties to do with what you want it to represent. Quantity is related, but not indicative, of broadness. It will close specifics and leave open vagues.

Comment: Which is exactly why StrixVaria and I have been saying this answer isn't even a solution at all!

Comment: @Bruce So when I used the word precise I meant `meet the requirements asked for`.  The issue here is that popularity out weights meeting requirements when it comes to voting.  A popular game, while not meeting requirements, will accumulate votes despite the fact that it doesn't meet the requirements.  This is the issue with popularity. Additionally there is no reason to assume that people will do further research before making a purchasing, unless you are suggesting we put up a big red sign saying `WARNING these suggestions may be completely wrong, do not purchase without additional research'

Comment: Let's take a practical example: A game-rec from someone who enjoyed Modern Warfare 2 and is looking for a similar first person shooter with an emotional single player story set in the near future. The asker selects Modern Warfare 1 as the correct answer but the answer Portal gets the most up-votes. Another person comes along looking for another game like MW2. He's already played MW1, so he goes to the next answer: Portal. He then goes out and buys Portal and is sorely disappointed as it is nothing like MW2 (one of the criteria). The person suffers monetarily and the site suffers in reputation.

Comment: @tzenes if someone makes purchasing decisions based on one opinion on one website, without consulting further reviews, demos or trailers, I'm guessing that someone has a very large library of purchased but "disappointing" games.

Comment: Also, as a general concept - **I** am going to vote on answers based on accuracy, not perceived quality. I will definitely downvote Portal in @tzenes's comment above, even though it's a superb game. And I don't think I will be the only one, though I acknowledge popular games are likely to get upvoted if only because many users are familiar with them.

Comment: @tzenes I hardly think the site is to blame for someone's impulsive buying habits. No single website should be blindly trusted for shopping advice, why should we be treated different?

Comment: @tzenes On a different note. Like @Oak said, many people would  downvote the Portal answer, but the whole issue is whether they would be the majority. This option here is strongly based on the idea that the precision-based downvotes would outnumber the popularity-based upvotes when the question is precise enough. If I'm not mistaken, your concern (on this specific point) is that they won't, and it's a valid concern.

Comment: Maybe the precision-downvotes will prevail except for very high popularity cases (like portal); maybe that will happen at first, but the general community will learn to downvote wrong answers with time (since we'll keep trying to enforce it); and maybe it'll just fail.

Comment: @Grace I concede to your point on that. I was aware of that issue when I proposed this, but you convinced me its consequences might out-weight the benefits.

Comment: In general, given the number of people voting for this option (though I don't have access to the raw number of up-votes) compared to the lack of people defending it in the comments, I wonder if people aren't just voting for the first option that tried to keep [game-rec]s alive. I suggest we add a recommendation to the answer telling people to at least glance through the comments before voting or something like that. It is CW, so feel free to mess with it.

Comment: You can actually see the raw number of upvotes, albeit requiring some calculation, using the [timeline view](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/1491/timeline/). I'll save you the trouble and point out that it is currently 66/-10.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting a "page not found" with that link.

Comment: @Grace That link is a 404 for me.

Comment: @Strix and Bruce - Fixed the link. I made a typo, eheh ♪

Comment: You are free to withdraw your suggestion if you feel that it is too dangerous to even be considered as an option anymore. If you plan to do so, I will assist you in editing the post to summarize the issues that have been brought up over these 60-some comments.

Comment: @bruce When I read statements like this `I hardly think the site is to blame for someones impulsive buying habits`, I hear `It's ok to give bad advice because they shouldnt be following it`. Regardless of what buying habits a person has the advice we give influences people we should not be influencing them towards buying something they dont want. We give advice to people on a variety of issues; we use the voting system to split the good advice from the bad. Our value as a site is directly proportional to how good advice we give. If game-recs cannot guarantee good advice then they don't belong!

Comment: @tzenes You misunderstand me. That sentence means exactly what's written on it. I agree wholeheartedly that good voting defines the value of the site, and whether good voting will happen or not is a very big concern. I'm not convinced it will, but I'm not convinced it won't either. That's all I meant.

Comment: @Grace Yes, you have won me over.

Comment: @Bruce So then ignoring the issue of buying habits (which I am still upset about, but willing to let go for now), you seem to have suggested before that poor voting habits will occur on game-recs when you said `it isn't that much of a problem`.  Are you now saying you aren't convinced it will occur or do you think it might occur but `isn't a problem`, or some combination of these two points...

Comment: You know we have other places for these discussions you know?

Comment: @Ivo - In this case it may be preferable to keep the discussion in the question for maximum visibility. If it does move to chat, anything pertinent should be linked here.

Comment: There's a thing called bookmarked conversations @sjohnston, which keeps perfect track off chat discussions ;-)

Comment: @tzenes I said `it isn't that much of a problem` because it will still happen, but in a smaller scale. If a question is precise, it's a lot easier to determine wrong answers and downvote them. That will lead to more downvoting of wrong answers, and less (but not zero) upvoting of wrong-but-popular answers. The whole concern is whether the former will outnumber the latter or not. That's the thing I'm not convinced either way about. At first, I was more convinced that precision voting would prevail. If it doesn't, than that *is* very much of a problem.

Comment: @Grace Why on earth is this removed?  When we start removing opinions we disagreed with?  What is the point of putting an issue to vote if we feel free to disenfranchise people's votes because we don't like their proposal?  Certainly I disagreed with this issue strongly, but that doesn't make it right to cancel out the opinions of the 66 people who agreed with it.

Comment: @tzenes It has nothing to do with disagreed opinions, and I'm a bit offended that you accuse me of such. This is about actual policy-making, and a policy which *cannot* reasonably be enforced is much different than one which I would merely dislike enforcing. Equivalently, what happened here is that Bruce has deleted his post (which he is *completely* free to do, you know, and doesn't even need my help!). But instead of leaving a wide gap where no one understands why the highest voted post has vanished into thin air, I explained what transpired over this huge comment thread as an announcement.

Comment: @tzenes I'm not particularly enthused to have done this, not even remotely. But in the same vein that we never even planned this process to weed out non-policies, we also didn't plan the process in a method that handles when a voting option is removed. If it must be done, we could possibly restart the voting and extend the deadline. I'm fine with that. I'm not supporting the "unconditionally allow game-rec" to be ironic, you know.

Comment: @Grace You may not have been the one who removed it but you are the one who rolled back to Bruce's with drawl and you are the one who locked the thread.  You are a mod and I hold you to a much higher standard than Bruce or anyone here.  Now I completely agree with you that this vote was taken without sufficient planning. I even mentioned in the planning thread something like this would happen, and while Oak acknowledged the possibility nothing was done to mitigate it.  [Grace's full explanation to me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/230684#230684)

Comment: Ultimately, disenfranchising people's votes is 8 kinds of unacceptable.  If we believe this vote has reached the point where it is unsustainable then I'm going to have to ask it be abandoned and we start over or look for different recourse.  If people are unwilling to restart the vote then the only reasonable alternative is that this option be put back into the running.

Comment: @tzenes What rollback are you talking about? I originally locked the answer because, *again*, this is equivalently a deleted post, which cannot be voted or commented on normally. But I decided instead that it should be unlocked so that there can still be discussion - I likewise considered that to be more useful to people than to just leave it untouchable like a deleted post. I then made a *request* that it not be rolled back by just anyone because in the same vein, a deleted post can't be undeleted by the community.

Comment: @Grace I'm not sure this is relevant but Revision 5 (by Bruce) is a rollback to his original proposal, and Revision 6 (by yourself) shows it be modified to the current state (or close to it).  Regardless the point is irrelevant. I don't believe anyone has the authority to remove those 66 votes other than those 66 people.  While the concept of deleting an answer translates well to Q&A, it does not extend to voting in this fashion. While Bruce may now disagree with his post he does not have the right to remove it the way he does an answer.

Comment: @tzenes The rollback is unrelated, then. We did not create this process under the assumption that all policies proposed are binded to existence upon being posted. Allow me to be hypothetical for a moment, but consider if a user posts a ridiculous policy as a joke. It's meant as good natured fun and not a serious idea, but against the expectations of that user, it manages to earn 100 votes. Does this mean we are locked and stuck with a joke policy? Is it just the folly of the user for having posted the policy in the first place?

Comment: @Grace all of these are good criticisms of the vote in general.  If at 35 I decide to run for President and win 51% of the vote (by which I mean the Electoral College), despite my obvious lack of qualifications, I am still President.  The is the problem with allowing for an open venue for people to vote on. This is the issue I raised ahead of time (though more practical than a Joke policy), and the reason I said `it does make me hesitant to support such a wide spread voting initiative`.

Comment: If you feel, as I do, the only solution to keep this vote open is to disenfranchise voters, then I am arguing that this vote should not be kept open.  We need to nip this one now before it grows into a larger issue.  Its clear this vote was not undertaken with sufficient preparation and should be abandoned until such time we can take that preparation.

Comment: @tzenes As mentioned twice now, I am fine with restarting the process in some fashion, be it just a vote reset or reworking the process as a whole.

Comment: @Grace ok, then I'm voting to close this poll, you can be the 5th vote if we can find 3 others

Answer (score 43):

### Let them be answered; don't close them. (unconditionally)

At some points, it seems like people are losing sight of why they even want to allow game recommendations in the first place. And unless I'm completely mistaken, the reason we want to allow game recommendations is because we want to provide help to people who are lacking of the next game they want to play.

It is more conducive to that goal of helping people if we simply allow them without so many hoops to jump through. Restricting things based on the quantity of potential answers or the assumed specificity of the scope are compromises made with the illusion of satisfying both sides, but they don't really do that well. We transform the argument of "These do/do not belong here" into "This is specific/not specific enough", and the fighting simply continues. That kind of solution leads us to all the same problems we already deal with. And the end result is that the majority of people who would come here for game recommendations would still have everything closed.

The fact is, all the same channels that we would direct these "broad scope" users to? They all work equally well for the "narrow scope" users! All these "compromises" we develop serve to do little more than make the process very uncomfortable to the majority of users and may also produce the image of a very elitist community. After all, if those avenues work for narrow, why do they get the privilege to ask on the parent Q&A?

**Forget the middle ground**, it doesn't work. If we want game recommendations, we should allow them full scale.

Comment: While I approve of encouraging additional options, I think the opinion needs a little reasoning to back it up.

Comment: @sjohnston I'll back this up. I'd actually prefer this route before I'd take something that closes things unless they're "specific enough". Really bad broad repositories are no different than overly broad questions of other types, they are too broad to answer effectively and we have a Not-A-Real-Question close reason for just that. But if it's not too broad, that just means there are more possible answers which makes it easier to give people what can help, which is our very goal as a site. There is a wide area in game-rec in which broad scope is actually *better*.

Comment: Or, to summarize it: if game-rec are acceptable and we consider them valuable, I think it's more conducive to our ability to serve them if we don't make it such a hassle to ask them and get meaningful results. Bad recs have the same flaws that other bad questions do. Why be elitist and only allow recs which are hard to answer and which only a handful of the users on the site stand a chance of knowing any qualifiers? Why make it harder to provide the services we are trying to advertise?

Comment: The other main advantage of this route is that if we simply choose to have a blanket acceptance, then there's no dispute. With arbitrary guidelines to judge on, we're going to just see more bickering between people, just it's going to be on whether a topic really is or is not specific enough. We'll be fighting the same, stupid battle that has been going on for the past 4 months and is the reason why we're trying to make a final decision in the first place, and why it's being established with no appeal for at least a year.

Comment: @Grace Note Excelent, that my point. If we are going to accept this, we should accept all. that the point of getting a separate "Gaming Recommendations" site.

Comment: @Grace Can you edit that in to the answer?

Comment: @CRoss Which part?

Comment: I made it a wiki

Comment: @grace @cross Excellent supporting comments Grace. I agree that these should be added/summarized in the answer itself. (I'll do it tomorrow, when I'm back on a PC, if I haven't been beaten to the punch.

Comment: All or None. No compromise.

Comment: +1 for being a sane solution.

Answer (score 37):

While I agree with @badp in general there are some cases where I think a game recommendation question *might be* OK.

The ones that spring to mind are requests for games that can be played by people with disabilities either physical (visual or motor control issues), or behavioural.

In these cases it's not just a case of "I like X, what else will I like", or "my PC has this spec, what will run" but asking for a game that will meet a very particular set of needs.

#### UPDATE

I would be the first to admit that this isn't an ideal solution as you will get people arguing over where the line should be drawn. An "all or nothing" policy is **much** easier to enforce as there is no debate.

If the [Game Rec](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations) site takes off then the question becomes moot - **all** game recommendation questions go there and **none** are allowed here.

Comment: I agree that accessibility is a special case. A crappy computer however doesn't make you disabled, so I wouldn't support that border line

Comment: @Ivo - On reflection I think that I wouldn't either.

Comment: Would it be accurate to summarize this as "We basically call them off-topic, but allow *truly exceptional* questions", wherein there has to be a very good reason behind being an exception to our rule besides just "This is slightly more specific than that one"?

Comment: @Grace - You could put it like that ;)

Comment: @Christian - you can (usually) do something about a low spec machine. You can't do something about a disability.

Comment: You could fly an airplane through this back door.  Would this question get closed?.  "I like to take my old crappy laptop with me on airplane flights to play games on.  The problem is I don't have a USB mouse, the space bar is broken, I'm terrible at games, I get migraines from staring at the screen too intently, and I hate to read.  Are there any games I could play that would accommodate these specific needs on my next flight?"

Comment: @Christian - yes "Too Localised".

Comment: @ChrisF Closed by whom?  It would take an incredible amount of discernment to detect these kinds of questions when they're deliberately dressed up to appear otherwise.

Comment: I spent many years working as a graduate student in Computer Science and a large part of my focus was on creating games for children with Cognitive Disabilities Beyond learning how effective video games can be at combating the psychological disabilities caused by Fetal Alcohol Syndrome and FASD I learned that gamers are a bad group to ask about helpful games. Talking with psychologists allowed my to understand (and design) games that were more appropriate. I realize that people with disabilities, children, loved ones are sensitive topics but I don't think that makes these questions appropriate

Comment: Touché for the disabled kids, I change my mind based on what @tzenes just said *[†: I apparently enjoy editing in acutes]*

Comment: Now that tzenes has expertly dealt with the only example of an acceptable question given, are there any others?

Comment: I'd actually disagree with @Tzenes in general., while conceding his specific point. While it is *absolutely true* that we as a community are **completely** unsuited to help the sort of children he describes, this does not make us unable to help, for instance, an adult who has recently lost the use of one arm and is looking for games that can be played one handed - for one example. Not all disabilities are created equal, and questions of *accessibility* are not the same as questions of *assistance*. We are well equipped in many cases for the former. Not the latter.

Comment: @LessPop As if anything about a game depended on a player's number of arms.  External factors like these should have absolutely no bearing on game recs.  The only reason these examples aren't being shot down more rapidly and with more fervor is for fear of looking insensitive.

Comment: @Christian Well, actually, yes. Now given, there are alternate control schemes of all sorts floating around these days, but different people prefer to address disabilities and accessibility concerns in different ways. To perhaps use an example that isn't so readily short circuited by adaptive hardware, not all games offer adjustments suited to assisting those with certain debilitating visual impairments, but some do. Sites like [AbleGamers](http://www.ablegamers.com) speak to the specific needs, and the widely varied success of games in meeting them better than I ever could though.

Comment: @Christian on top - Off-topic, belongs on boardgames.

Comment: @Less I think you're kind of making an assumption on _Accessibility_, and to your credit you may be correct, but that is really something that a Physical Therapist should be making the decision on.  While you or I might guess that you can/can't play Starcraft with 1 arm, without real experience its largely conjecture.  I'd prefer not to speculate when possible as we may accidentally encourage someone with a disability to invest heavily in hardware and games that it turns out they can't use (or discourage them).

Comment: @tzenes: I'm hardly suggesting speculative answers. But I can tell you from personal experience, that, for example, Borderlands is a colorblind players worst nightmare. Whereas, for example, Left4Dead2 specifically features a color-blind mode to resolve *exactly* the same set of issues.

Comment: @Less Having been color blind my whole life I've never considered it a disability, but I'm not sure I see the value in a question "Recommend me which games I can play color blind," as it suffers from all the problems that normal game-recs suffer from.  It also suffers from the problem that I disagree with you about Borderlands as I had no trouble playing it.  Finally, if we're going to include Color-blind, should we also include Nearsited? Athsma? Poor Coordination? ADHA? Dyslexia?  These are all traits I have, but I wouldn't consider needing a special exemption the way: Having 1 arm, might.

Comment: Isn't the policy suggested here a bit vague? Even after Grace's attempt to clarify it in a comment, I'm still not sure what it means. What criteria will I use to decide whether a question should be closed or not? You listed two examples - one about accessibility, one about hardware limitations. OK, but what are we to do about anything in-between?

Comment: @Oak - That, of course, is the flaw with something that's not an "all or nothing" approach. I must admit on re-reading the comments that I'm starting to agree with @tzenes in that allowing accessibility questions is just as subjective as "normal" ones. I'll leave the suggestion here for a bit longer - but I'm happy for it to be "closed" if that's deemed the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm not saying we *have* to go an "all or nothing" route, I'm just saying we need a more clear-cut policy about when is something permitted. Perhaps, in addition to providing examples, you could also add the actual criteria you propose for the questions.

Comment: @Oak - OK, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 10):

Can we make a specific type of Close and point them to a specific route, hopefully something like the proposal for a Stack Exchange Gaming Recommendations found here:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations

Rather than try and be subjective which can be off-putting to new or any users, just close them all and point them somewhere where they can get their question answered, or just move them directly to the gaming recommendations site if it is on the Stack Exchange platform.

**UPDATED** to point to the existing Area 51 proposal.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations

Comment: Guess I should have researched that, a bit more, guess I'll make some edits.

Comment: I think "Stack Exchange Gaming Recommendations" would be the ideal, but some energy should be put into it to make sure it open some day. Then, those questions would need to be migrated instead of "mak[ing] a specific type of Close".

Comment: Normally on Super User we would leave a comment directing users to the alternative SE-sites, I don't think we need to change the Close UI to enable something similar

Comment: @Ivo check this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/

Comment: Those weren't in place several months ago @DavRob60

Comment: I agreed with this proposal and I am committed, but meanwhile, what should we do? Use the chat only? Or wait quietly until it goes to beta?

Answer (score 10):

#### Just Pick Already

We've discussed, we've argued, we've voted, and we've had problems with all of them.

I give up. I would like to cast my vote to empower our Mods to decide and enforce a policy on Game-Recs. I don't care if its Allowed. I don't care if its Off Topic. I don't care if its some gray area in between.

Even if its a flawed policy, it can be revisited later by our next mod team, or in a year, or whenever.

Please just choose one, any one, and enforce it. I'll use my close/open vote to help.

Comment: Yes!  I was going to post exactly the same thing.  I don't care what the majority opinion is, I care about the opinion of the people that have the most invested in this site.  We will soon have a chance to elect moderators.  I would like those moderators to make the decision.  In the meantime, I'm fine with our current moderators making their own decision, with the understanding that it can be changed after the elections.

Answer (score 6):

I propose that we create a couple of community-FAQ like questions that cater to those that favor game-recommendations.

These would amongst others give users:

- good resources for discovering games or finding similar ones,
- explain you can discuss these things on our own Chat channel,
- a list of resources, such as Gametrailers, Metacritic and other resources for finding reputable opinions about games you might like.

These questions should **teach users to find this information themselves, rather than spelling it out for them.** This is really what this site is all about: learn from your fellow gamers!

New additions to the FAQs should be discussed on Meta or on chat and these should be created by mods (as they need to be community wiki).

Any other recommendation questions are closed as off-topic, following @badp's suggestion.

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but personally, I don't see why this has to be a separate choice from badp's proposal.  A question like "What resources are available for discovering games" is not strictly game-rec.  It does suffer from the usual issues that all list questions do, but I think it will prove useful, and provide a good outlet for all that game-rec energy.  And being a one-off special case and (presumably) community wiki, we don't really have to worry as much about reputation or vote pollution.

Answer (score 6):

We could set 2 team:

1. The **Game Recommendations Close Squad** (*GRCS*) will close those question as soon as they are asked or reopened.
2. Then, the **Game Recommendations Liberation League** (*GRLL*) will reopen them as soon as they notify the question was closed.

That way, we will have a balanced policy. With some practice we could make the **[closed]** mark blink.

Comment: I thought this was the current solution.

Comment: Indeed, it is!!!

Comment: +1 for balance, but only if I get a flashy 'gang tag' badge identifying me as a member of the Squad.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I haven't yet seen considered is that a goodly portion of our game and hardware recommendation questions are being migrated from Superuser.

It's no good for a question to be migrated here, only to have it become closed. The folks at SuperUser need to know to not push such questions here, should we decide that game rec questions should be closed.

Comment: [A few steps ahead of you](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1746/please-dont-migrate-game-recommendations-to-gaming-for-now-at-least). ♪ I don't recall that we get that many from Super User, though. A lot more often we get hardware troubleshooting than recommendations.

Comment: Ah, well this recent question is what sparked my thoughts in the first place: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12341/funny-christmas-game-for-ten-year-old-kid-closed

Comment: Here's the full list of all questions which have been migrated from Super User as of now: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9802/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10433/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11539/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11410/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12199/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9241/, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9393/, and finally http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12341/. ♪

Answer (score -5):

Voting for Game rec ? Easy.. rate 1 to 5 + 80 character comment. that's it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're proposing here?  I'm not sure what you mean by "rate 1 to 5".

Comment: As it seems MMO-Tragic isn't going to clarify, I'll try...  My guess is that he means "Allow game rec questions unconditionally. Each answer should be a single game recommendation. People should then add comments to the answers, including a 1-5 point rating of the answer and comments to back up that rating (of a maximum of 80 characters)."

Comment: I only got this alert recently. rate 1 to 5 i thought would be self explanatory. 1= rubbish, 5=awesome and an 80 character comment... not much more to explain....