# Considering recommendation requests are arguably out of place on Gaming, where should I ask them?

Tags: discussion, game-recommendations

I'm looking for a very specific genre of game, that should yield no more than 2-3 recommendations, and yet, that would be great.

However, considering the [debate](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations) on game recommendation questions, which tends to prohibit them so far, I'm left wondering where would be an appropriate place on the web to ask mine.

I am aware of many gaming forums and whatnot, but their communities are always extremely scarce, biased or centered on specific genres around which they seem to have built.

Where, then, should I ask for specific game recommendations?

EDIT: This should be moved to Meta, I presume. Sorry for the confusion.

EDIT 2: I stumbled upon the [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20517/game-recommendations) for game recs. I am totally supporting this project, since while I think it's a perfectly good policy to restrain recs from Gaming, there has to be an alternative somewhere.