# Why are questions asking for games that focus on specific mechanics against the rules?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, game-recommendations

I made a mistake. I asked [This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65454/what-games-focus-on-building-and-customizing-a-team#comment92127_65454), which is clearly against the faqs listed, and for that I'm sorry (I have already flagged it for deletion). But I don't understand why this site doesn't have room for a discussion of mechanics between games. I understand that gaming is a wide scope, but I'm not asking a question about a wide enough array of games to swamp the post with more information than is legible. I'm not asking for opinions, or subjective facts. I am asking for games other users have found with similar mechanics to the ones I listed. I am looking for something fact based, that I haven't been able to readily find answers for myself in more than 3 years of research.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for more games that do that, especially ones that focus on meaningful choices and lasting progression.

This is a "game catalogue" question. [We looked hard at them and game recommendation questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendations?sort=votes&pagesize=50), [held a vote](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations) and called them off the island. :)

Comment: I see. They lost by 4 votes. Well, I suppose that at least is something... Far from a majority, but plurality will have to do.

Comment: @Rhylok Actually it won by 27 votes as the +58 answer "doesn't count" (see the blockquote at the top)

Comment: @Rhylok If you go through all the questions with the [tag:game-recommendations] tag here on Meta, you'll see that it wasn't just a single voting instance that determined the fate of those questions. It was a discussion that lasted *months*, with strong opinions on both sides. Ultimately, it was determined better for the site's health as a whole to deem them off-topic. There were several problems inherent with game-rec questions that made them an ill fit for our Q&A system. It was not a decision that was made lightly by the community, trust me.

Comment: 33 votes even, since the downvotes didn't count.  So it was 78 to 45, which is probably as close to consensus as we have ever come on this site.