# List of games (or a game) that fit specific criteria

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, lists

One of the prohibited type of questions in Arqade (gaming.stackechange) is:

> Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an
>      existing game)

So where can we ask these type of questions? (for example, is there any other stackexchange site?)  (I'm not sure if this question is suitable for this meta site also)

It is reasonable to prohibit because it can be too broad and there can be too many answers. But if there are very specific situations, there can be very few answers as well.

Is there any way to make this type of question acceptable?

---

On the other hand, can we ask to find a single game with a certain criteria?

For example:

> What is the longest game?

Or maybe more specific:

> What is the longest game that has a female character and released in 90's?

Comment: By the way, Why would my question be downvoted? I just wanted to get clarification. And It is also replied with a great answer.

Comment: Negative voting on meta has a different purpose to its counterpart on the main arqade space. Here it means people don't agree with your proposed idea, as opposed to your question being offtopic or invalid as is the case on the main arqade space.

Comment: @deutschZuid: But I did not propose an idea, I just wanted to get clarification on the rule and wanted to get suggestions where to ask these type of questions. And I got two great suggestions that I did not know. But thanks for answering.

Comment: the 'idea-proposing' part of my comment wasn't the salient point...

Comment: What is the salient point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there's no way to make Game Recs acceptable on Arqade and there are no other SE sites where they are allowed. We had a long discussion about this during the site's inception, which ultimately ended up with the questions being banned. You can peruse the [game-recommendations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendations) tag to read Meta questions that dealt with this (the final vote being found [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1492/160)).

As you stated, Arqade is not a suitable place for this question. However, we do have a [blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/11/shopping-advice-for-gamers/) entitled Shopping Advice for Gamers, which can help you get started. In addition, asking for games with certain criteria still falls under the umbrella of "game recommendation".

These questions have several problems. First, they create inaccurate voting problems. For example, in the early days of the site, when one asked for a game recommendation, any answer that included *Portal* received a disproportionate amount of upvotes due to its popularity. When answering Game Rec questions, users tend to vote on the game listed, rather than the actual quality of the answer, which goes against the intent of voting on the site.

Second, it became difficult do determine a question's acceptability. Asking for any RPG was too broad, but asking for a RPG with turn-based elements, a cyberpunk setting, a minimum of 3 factions, and multiplayer would be too granular and difficult, if not nigh impossible to answer. What was too little criteria? What was too much? How, if at all, could these questions be useful to the Internet as a whole?

Historical trivia, which is what your final example would fall under, is also difficult to definitely determine for us, as that criteria is also difficult to judge, in addition to requiring us to have a full breadth of knowledge of every game released in the 90s. How would you measure longest? Single player campaign? Longest not counting all collectibles? 100%ing the game? There are too many variables just with the question's criteria, let alone trying to determine what actually could be considered the right answer.

So, sorry, Arqade is not the place for these questions. Check out the blog post I linked for some other resources on the Internet that could possibly help you out, or stop by our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge). Keep in mind that if you stop by chat, you need to have at least 20 rep to chat and that there are different activity levels throughout the day, so you may not be able to get an answer right away and/or there may be no one that actually is able to answer.

Comment: Software Recs accepts gamerec, if that hasn't changed since.

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed answer. I admit that, the examples I gave was still not specific enough but I got the idea. "Just do not ask" :). And thanks for the blog recommendation, that did not come to my mind.

Comment: @FEichinger: Also another nice answer. I checked there and seems like we can ask but we have to be very specific. They close broad ones.