# Is it allowed to ask tips about new games I want?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to ask this communinty about what new game to buy, giving information about genre and gameplay?

Comment: Again thanks for the anonymous downvote, it realy helps...

Comment: Downvotes on meta are usually disagreement with whatever you propose - in this case, asking us about game-recs.

Comment: Ok I understand, but downvoting is so easy, it would be nicer if people should only be able to vote if the leave a comment.

Comment: That is something that has been discussed to death here and on meta.stackexchange, and it is not likely to change. Votes are anonymous for various good reasons, and I suspect if you looked on M.SE, you could find many discussions about the topic.

Comment: What is m.se? If it is a website, it doesn't work here, it's an empty page.

Comment: M.SE - meta.stackexchange.com, the main meta site for the entire network.

Comment: Reason for my downvote: user demands downvote reasons.

Comment: The reason for the down votes is that the tour in the help section, where you can find what you should or should not ask about, specifically says "Don't ask about requests for game identification or recommendations" and "questions that are opinion-based or speculative". Don't take the down votes on this site personally, especially on meta. :) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I am not gonna comment everytime I downvote if it's something that can be easily explained by the faq. I have better use of my time thank you very much. But I do comment if it's not something clearly explained in the faq.

Comment: Nice to know that these points don't count, so go ahead downvote all you want lol

Answer (score 11):

No, asking for game recommendations on the main site is off topic. You can see one of the larger discussions on the topic [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations).

You are welcome to take your chances in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), however.

Comment: Sorry can't accept your answer, get this error: "You can't accept an answer"

Comment: @Coolen The message is likely cut off, saying that you can't accept the answer for a certain amount of time. I think it's usually 15 minutes before you can accept the first answer.

Comment: OK then I will accept it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, game recommendations of any sort are off topic here. Take a peek at our [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about what is and isn't on topic here.