# What's with this tag?

Tags: support, tags

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec

See above link.

I was looking to see if there were any tags for Game suggestions, or something similar and I was redirected to that: "game-rec" and so I proceeded to "ask question". When filling out the tags section I could not find "game-rec" or "game-suggestions".

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

Questions asking for game recommendations are [off topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1492/3114) on arqade.  I'm not sure how you found it, but long story short, the tag doesn't exist any more.

We used to add it to posts before closing them, but now I think the redirect is just a vestige from quite some time ago.

This tag should no longer be used, nor should recommendation questions befitting it be posted.

Answer (score 4):

That means nothing. You can go to [djhkjhkjsdfhfd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/djhkjhkjsdfhfd) and get the same result.

If you came from google then it may have been archived once upon a time and after all the questions with said tag had been removed the tag was then deleted.

A proper tag like [phantom-brave](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phantom-brave) will contain an "Info" link even if there is nothing in it. As with the [other](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10647/30879) [answers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/30879) here Game Suggestions/Recommendations are Off-topic

Comment: I found it from the search: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags go here, type in "Game-Suggestions" it should appear, you click that and it leads to that site in the question. But you can't use the "Game-suggestion" tag on questions

Comment: Ahh.  There we go.  [tag:game-recommendation] is synonymed to [tag:game-rec].  Should probably burn 'em both.

Comment: I don't know too much of the mechanics of synonymized tags but logically based from what @Frank said in the end, SE's database would have a redirect url entry saying something like "if going to  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-suggestions redirect to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-rec" and this redirect exists for Game-Suggestions so if Game-recs was removed it's unaffected.....though weird an orphaned tag hasn't been removed but then again i don't know when it was orphaned

Comment: would be curious to see what happens if you put in the url of a deleted synonymized tag to see if the redirect would still work

Comment: @Frank - did questions still exist with either tag? Because by the looks of things, tags with synonyms stick around so they still show up when searching on the [tags](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags) page. It might be worth raising with the SE team to auto-delete synonyms where the tags are unused...