# Should we have a migration path to Software Recs for game recommendation questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, game-recommendations, migration, migration-path-request

Currently our stance on game recommendation questions are [that they are closed, per this meta article](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations).

However, I've found that Software Recs SE does have the tag [game](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) that allows people to post game recommendation questions, provided they fit a certain set of criteria (per the tag wiki), and that they are not too broad.

Should we set up a migration path to the site then for game recommendation questions, as they appear to be on topic there? For what it's worth, the tag [game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) has 46 questions asked so far, with some of those questions closed.

Should we stick to our guns and stick with the "Questions that ask for recommendations of games, software, or hardware are off topic. For more information on why these sorts of questions don't work here...", or should we instead set up a migration path to software recs.se?

Comment: It seems that there is also a third option: keep the current close reason, but also mention in the close message or in comments that the question might be suited for Software Recs.

Comment: My understanding is that we removed most migration paths due to being used improperly..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, for the same reasons we don't migrate to GameDev.

SoftwareRecs' policy on games is [extremely strict](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-video-game-related-questions-on-topic/224#224). Game questions there must solve problems- not alleviate boredom and not solve a particular individual's tastes. Almost all the game recommendations I've seen on Arqade violate those rules. The only questions that might be allowed are mod recommendations, which are better off kept here and reworded.

Arqade has had trouble in the past with migrations. We no longer migrate to GameDev thanks to users sending them "How do I start modding?" questions which are against their rules. This situation would be no different. Users would send poor game recommendations there, have the migrations rejected, and SoftwareRecs would close the migration path.

In the exceptional circumstances where a game should be migrated, mods can still move it.

Comment: In general, the rule is, "We don't migrate crap."  We have no set migration paths because our track record has shown that the vast majority of questions aren't actually worth migrating.  We create a path, it's going to get a lot of rejected migrations.  Better to let the mods handle migrating those few that are worth migrating.